# Matlab: Renaming files in a folder sequentially

Tags: matlab, file, renaming

If there are the following  files in the folder C:\test\:

file1.TIF, file2.TIF .... file100.TIF

Can MatLab automatically rename them to:

file_0001.TIF, file_0002.TIF, .... file_0100.TIF?

Comment: I guess if you load them in a for loop and save them with the new name you could do it. I dont know if there is a way to do it without open and closeing them

Comment: Look into `movefile`. I wonder if there could be a no-loop cell array approach though, or maybe with `cellfun`, which I doubt would bring any performance improvement, maybe just elegancy at the most.

Comment: Thanks #Ander Biguri, and #Divakar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No-loop approach -

```
directory  = 'C:\test\'; %//' Directory where TIFF images are present
filePattern = fullfile(directory, 'file*.tif'); %//' files pattern with absolute paths
old_filename = cellstr(ls(filePattern)) %// Get the filenames
file_ID = strrep(strrep(old_filename,'file',''),'.TIF','') %// Get numbers associated with each file
str_zeros = arrayfun(@(t) repmat('0',1,t), 5-cellfun(@numel,file_ID),'uni',0) %// Get zeros string to be pre-appended to each filename
new_filename = strcat('file_',str_zeros,file_ID,'.TIF') %// Generate new filenames
cellfun(@(m1,m2) movefile(m1,m2),fullfile(directory,old_filename),fullfile(directory,new_filename)) %// Finally rename files with the absolute paths
```

**Edit 1:**

For a case when you have the filenames as `file27.TIF`, `file28.TIF`, `file29.TIF` and so on and you would like to rename them as `file0001.TIF`, `file0002.TIF`, `file0003.TIF` and so on respectively, try this -

```
directory  = 'C:\test\'; %//' Directory where TIFF images are present
filePattern = fullfile(directory, 'file*.tif'); %//' files pattern with absolute paths
old_filename = cellstr(ls(filePattern)) %// Get the filenames
file_ID = strrep(strrep(old_filename,'file',''),'.TIF','') %// Get numbers associated with each file

file_ID_doublearr = str2double(file_ID)
file_ID_doublearr = file_ID_doublearr - min(file_ID_doublearr)+1

file_ID = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(file_ID_doublearr)))

str_zeros = arrayfun(@(t) repmat('0',1,t), 4-cellfun(@numel,file_ID),'uni',0) %// Get zeros string to be pre-appended to each filename
new_filename = strcat('file',str_zeros,file_ID,'.TIF') %// Generate new filenames
cellfun(@(m1,m2) movefile(m1,m2),fullfile(directory,old_filename),fullfile(directory,new_filename)) %// Finally rename files with the absolute paths
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to do it without the loop.

Comment: @excaza Yeah I guess `arrayfun` and `cellfun` only bring "elegancy" to the table, I doubt if there would be performance improvement though.

Comment: Thank you so much. How about if I have the following files in a folder: file27.TIF, file28.TIF, file29.TIF. Can I rename them starting from 0001 i.e. rename them to: file0001.TIF, file0002.TIF, file0003.TIF

Comment: @Mosawi Yes I think so. After you have `file_ID`, do this - `file_ID = file_ID - 26`, `str_zeros = arrayfun(@(t) repmat('0',1,t), 4-cellfun(@numel,file_ID),'uni',0)` and finally `new_filename = strcat('file',str_zeros,file_ID,'.TIF')`

Comment: For (file_ID - 6), I get the error "Undefined function 'minus' for input arguments of type 'cell'". Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Mosawi Sorry I away for sometime. Check out the **Edit 1**.

Comment: @Mosawi No problem! :) Now if you have files with names as `file44.TIF, file45.TIF, file46.TIF`, it would rename them starting from 0001, that is `file0001.TIF, file0002.TIF, file0003.TIF`. Give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more robust method:

```
dirlist = dir(fullfile(mypath,'*.TIF'));
fullnames = {dirlist.name}; % Get rid of one layer of cell array-ness

[~,fnames,~] = cellfun(@fileparts,fullnames,'UniformOutput',false); % Create cell array of the file names from the output of dir()
fnums = cellfun(@str2double,regexprep(fnames,'[^0-9]','')); % Delete any character that isn't a number, returns it as a vector of doubles
fnames = regexprep(fnames,'[0-9]',''); % Delete any character that is a number

for ii = 1:length(dirlist)
    newname = sprintf('%s_%04d.TIF',fnames{ii},fnums(ii)); % Create new file name

    oldfile = fullfile(mypath,dirlist(ii).name); % Generate full path to old file
    newfile = fullfile(mypath,newname);          % Generate full path to new file

    movefile(oldfile, newfile); % Rename the files
end
```

Though this will accomodate filenames of any length, it does assume that there are no numbers in the filename other than the counter at the end. MATLAB likes to throw things into nested cell arrays, so I incorporated `cellfun` in a couple places to bring things into more manageable formats. It also allows us to vectorize some of the code.